# Competitive co-worker changed their job title

Tags: colleagues, title

I work for a small holdings company. I am one of two people competing for work building websites. My co-worker's job title - according to the company - is Senior Web Designer. My job title is Web Developer. There has been no announcement but they changed their email signature to Senior Web Developer. This person is in no way a Senior Web Developer - I have seen their code. They are in no way even as good as me.

But I found out from HR that their boss gave them the title bump three months ago.

I fear they are presenting themself to businesses within the company as a Senior Web Developer - including to the execs - who are going to pick them over me.

What can I do? Recently my business clients are being assigned to them. Should I go to HR? Please don't advise me to talk with them. This wasn't a typo on their part.

I think what I am looking for is legal advice.

Comment: Who changed the signature? Why can't you change yours?

Comment: They changed the signature. The signature in the email isn't controlled by the company - we create our own signatures so they changed it. As for me, I haven't earned the job title of Senior Web Developer - it would be misleading to do that.

Comment: Just because someone has a senior title doesn't mean that they are better or know more than someone without it. Sure they may get picked over someone without it but that doesn't mean they don't deserve the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do anything especially for software job title, which are not regulated like 'Doctor' or 'Professor' etc... heck, even the title 'engineer' is not regulated in software development - anyone can say he is a Senior Software Engineer without having a Master's degree.

What you can do though, is to discuss about it with the manager or whoever decided for this title 'bump' and explain your concerns about the new work you are not having because of it. Also, talk about having you too the same title - or even another one (Lead Software Dev, etc...) to reflect better the reality (don't do it on your own, but explain to the shareholders the facts about code quality, experience, relative titles, etc...).

Comment: I had discussions with 3 bosses - mine, the IT Director and then IT Executive. We discussed my skills, what I've done and where I want to go - and they discussed where they think this job is going and what changes we need to make to get where both of us want my position to go. It turned out well and as for the Senior Web Designer turned Senior Web Developer - HR said they did it to impress new clients. Personally I think that may backfire but they have me, who does all their Web Development work, while they make pretty websites.

Answer (score 5):

From your recent comment it seems that the title bump was official, in which case there is nothing you can do about it really.

Rightly or wrongly your employer has chosen to give them the title, and I get that it sucks for you if this results in them "winning" more work then you (especially since you feel that they aren't as good at coding as you are) but there's no standard or legal definitions when it comes to "Senior Web Developer" or "Senior Web Designer" and kicking up a fuss to HR about this is going to make you look jealous at best and spiteful at worst.

Your options are realistically:

1. **Ask your manager for a title bump**

You've already indicated that you don't think this is the answer as you feel that their title is the problem. I'd suggest reconsidering this stance though because I genuinely think this is the best option. You need to stop wasting time and energy worrying about something that is out of your control and start focussing on something that is.

2. **Do nothing**

If the colleague in question really can't deliver on the sorts of projects they are being assigned with their shiny new title then sooner or later they will crash and burn. You carry on working diligently and be there to look good and pick up the pieces when they do.

Comment: Yeah, in terms of 1, if OP genuinely believes they are of a better standard than their counterpart, and the company has chosen to make that person a senior developer, there is no reason for them to not make OP a senior developer. It's not like there is some form of accreditation for the title of senior developer, this is merely what the company has deemed to be a senior developer skillset (then again perhaps there is some alternative reason for the title, e.g. perhaps he has more non-developmental responsibilities).

Comment: @delinear Exactly.. what the "Senior" prefix means is very much dependent upon how the company defines it Some do it on length of service, some on responsibility, and some on perceived skill level. I've even seen it used purely to  make a particular employee feel appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> What can I do?

Discuss this with **your manager**.  Simply *ask* them, hey I noticed person X's title changed, were they promoted?  If not, you can take the conversation from there regarding the title change.  Come at it from the angle you feel you are at least equal to them, **not** that you care about their title.  Your only concerned with **your** title.

The other thing I would be *tempted* to try is to just change your title to match and see if anyone notices.

Comment: *The other thing I would be tempted to try is to just change your title to match and see if anyone notices.*  - This seems loaded with unforeseen negative consequences.

Comment: Just found out from HR their boss gave them the title bump three months ago. I think what I am looking for is legal advice.

Comment: @S.Jensen Even though your coworker's promotion is official, this advice still holds. You should be talking to your manager about your career trajectory. If your coworker isn't as good as you, but has been given high visibility projects, I would just wait until he messes the projects and let the customers do the complaining.

Comment: While changing your job title arbitrarily is probably a bad idea, of manager is OK with the coworker changing their title, then it would be reasonable to ask "Are you OK with me changing my title too?"

Comment: I spoke with HR. They told me to speak with the person who made the recommendation. That is going to turn into a "crap" show. Getting a job title bump isn't the answer. The problem isn't my title the problem is theirs. They are  Junior at best.

Comment: Let me put it this way. They were a Senior Web Designer - and a very good one. For them to become a Senior Web Developer is like me, a Web Developer - with some design experience - suddenly getting the title of Senior Web Designer.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings That is why the key word in that sentence is *tempted*.